# Android Project Dependency Needs Different Version of Android Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, gradle, version, build-tools

The gradle build of my Android project is failing because a dependency of my project needs an older version of the android gradle plugin:

```
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/android/spring-android-core/1.0.1.RELEASE/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/android/spring-android-rest-template/1.0.1.RELEASE/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.0.7.RELEASE/spring-asm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.7.RELEASE/spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/social/spring-social-core/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-social-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/android/spring-android-auth/1.0.1.RELEASE/spring-android-auth-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.1.1/jackson-annotations-2.1.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.1.1/jackson-core-2.1.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.1.2/jackson-databind-2.1.2.jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':myapp'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myapp:classpath'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
     Required by:
         phase1:myapp:unspecified > com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.1.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 20.894 secs
```

My project uses com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0, but the dependency, com.jakewharton.hugo, is looking for gradle:0.7.+.

Here are my gradle build files.

Top-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Subproject build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'hugo'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
..
..
..
```

Looking up Hugo on Github, I verified that release 1.1.0 does ask for the version 0.7.+, but the latest code (unreleased) use the new version (1.1.0)

Is there a way to allow Hugo to build with the old version, while building the rest of my project with the new one?

OR

I copied the top level [Hugo source directory from Github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo) into my project.  How do I tell gradle to find the hugo plugin there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We experienced the same issue. If you change your repository to mavenCentral() from jcenter(), it should resolve the issue. Its also possible to have both repositories.